# iOS - Reuseable UIView Subclass

Tags: ios, uiview, subclass, reusability

I am trying to build a few different UIView subclasses to display information to my app users.
One problem I am having is being able to call the view more than once.

Here is the testing call:

```
if(rewardsView==nil){
    rewardsView = [[RewardsView alloc] init];
    [rewardsView showRewardType:RewardsAttack withXP:100 withZBucks:10 isCritical:NO];
}else{
    [rewardsView showRewardType:RewardsAttack withXP:200 withZBucks:20 isCritical:NO];
}
```

Here is the Code to initialize and display:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH, DEVICE_HEIGHT);

        //Z-Bucks
        zBucksIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rewards-z-bucks"];
        zBucksView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(DEVICE_WIDTH/4-zBucksIcon.size.width/2, DEVICE_HEIGHT/2-zBucksIcon.size.height/2-12, zBucksIcon.size.width, zBucksIcon.size.height+25)];
        [zBucksView setImage:zBucksIcon];
        zBucksView.alpha = 0;

        zBucksLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, zBucksIcon.size.height, zBucksIcon.size.width,25)];
        zBucksLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        zBucksLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        zBucksLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans Condensed" size:24];
        zBucksLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        zBucksLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        zBucksLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
        [zBucksView addSubview:zBucksLabel];

        //XP
        xpIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rewards-xp"];
        xpView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(DEVICE_WIDTH/4*3-xpIcon.size.width/2, DEVICE_HEIGHT/2-xpIcon.size.height/2-12, xpIcon.size.width, xpIcon.size.height+25)];
        [xpView setImage:xpIcon];

        xpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, xpIcon.size.height, xpIcon.size.width,25)];
        xpLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        xpLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        xpLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans Condensed" size:24];
        xpLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        xpLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        xpLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
        [xpView addSubview:xpLabel];
        xpView.alpha = 0;

        [self addSubview:zBucksView];
        [self addSubview:xpView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)showRewardType:(RewardsType)type withXP:(int)xp withZBucks:(int)zBucks isCritical:(BOOL)critical{

    //Set Values
    zBucksLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%i",zBucks];
    xpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%i",xp];

    if(type==RewardsAttack){

    }
    if(type==RewardsHeal){

    }
    if(type==RewardsDaily){

    }

    UIWindow *window = [appDelegate window];
    [window addSubview:self];
    [self animateRewards];
}
```

Here is the code that dismisses (after some animation functions are called, not shown here):

```
-(void)dismissRewards{
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    //Reset Views
    zBucksView.alpha = 0;
    xpView.alpha = 0;
    [zBucksView setFrame:CGRectMake(DEVICE_WIDTH/4-zBucksIcon.size.width/2, DEVICE_HEIGHT/2-zBucksIcon.size.height/2-12, zBucksIcon.size.width, zBucksIcon.size.height+25)];
    [xpView setFrame:CGRectMake(DEVICE_WIDTH/4*3-xpIcon.size.width/2, DEVICE_HEIGHT/2-xpIcon.size.height/2-12, xpIcon.size.width, xpIcon.size.height+25)];
}
```

Comment: You don't exactly say what symptoms you're seeing.  Is the `rewardsView` in the first bit of code a property, ivar, local variable...?

Comment: plwase explain what do you want to achieve? update the one view to show different values? or do you want two instances of the view visible. what is not working?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify that first code snippet is the calling of the custom uiview from a view controller. What I want to happen, is to be able to call the custom view several times without having to re-initialize. It can only be called one at a time. i.e. A player attacks an enemy, the results are shown in this custom uiview as rewards (money / xp). The player will be able to attack an enemy several times, so the rewards view must be able to be called each time. Right now it only shows the first time its called. Hope that clarifies.